# To solve out of memory using large heap

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am making an app which uses many bitmap processing. Bcoz of this my app goes many a time out of memory.
I know i can use memory cache or file cache to stop this out of memory error but instead of that i am using android:largeheap=true property just for ease.
My question is...does it have any side effect on the app? I know it will use other apps RAM by force closing other apps....
Is there any other side effects on behaviour of my app?

Comment: Yes.  Because you do not understand how to calculate, measure and control the heap used by your app, all you have done by requesting an increased heap is to delay the point at which your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using large images, try to place them inside a [WeakReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html). I did the same thing in my app, and it did wonders with the memory usage.

Comment: In normal Java this works.  In Android, as of 3.0 a WeakReference does not persist-  they get deleted the moment the last strong reference goes out of scope.  The correct way in Android is to use an LRUCache instead.